# OutOfMemory error in toString when ISO-8859-1 encoding in SuSE Linux

Tags: java, linux, out-of-memory, iso-8859-1

I've been beating my head on this issue for a while.  I'm taking a 27K encoded string (similar to URL encoding) and turning it back into a 9K "ISO-8859-1" plaintext string.

```
byte outarray[] = new byte[decoded_msg_length]; // 9K
byte inarray[];
try {
  inarray = instring.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // eg: "ÀÀÀÚßÐÀÀÃÐéÙÓåäàÈÂÁÙÈ...."
  inarray = null; // free up whatever memory possible.
  // ... for loop decodes chunks of 4 bytes...

  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
  System.out.println("freeMemory1="+runtime.freeMemory()); // freeMemory1=86441120
  // yes I've tried methods like new String( outarray, "ISO-8859-1" );, etc.
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byteStream.write(outarray);
  outarray=null;
  runtime.gc();

  System.out.println("freeMemory2="+runtime.freeMemory()); //freeMemory2=133761568
  // return new String(outarray,"ISO-8859-1"); // OutOfMemoryException thrown here
  // return new String(outarray); // OutOfMemoryException thrown here too
  return byteStream.toString("ISO-8859-1"); // OutOfMemoryException thrown here also
  // sample output: "JOHN H SMITH  123 OAK ST..."
} catch( IOException ioe ) {
  ...
}
// Thrown exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:510)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:232)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:195)
    ...
```

It looks like I have plenty of memory.  This same code runs fine with less than half as much free memory in Windows.  I'm running this as a single standalone class.  Anyone know of any Linux encoding issues with a JRE memory leak?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pxi32dev-20080315 (SR7))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Linux x86-32 j9vmxi3223-20080315 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20080314_17962_lHdSMr
JIT  - 20080130_0718ifx2_r8
GC   - 200802_08)
JCL  - 20080314
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java Heap Size may have a different default limit in your Linux environment vs Windows. You can check this via the Runtime.maxMemory() method.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()

If the limit is smaller under Linux you can increase it via the -Jmx command-line argument to java,

```
java -Xmx1024m YourClassNameHere
```

The 1024m will increase the size of the heap to 1GB, you can adjust the amount as needed. This is a max amount, your program may use much less.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, though I'm not sure the exact reason why it occurs - most likely some internal static buffer variable.  Even though the error throws at the toString, the fix was to resize decoded_msg_length to be the same as instring.

For some reason I have yet to fathom, instring.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") sets the size of the some internal buffer filled by byteStream.toString("ISO-8859-1").  Setting the decoded_msg_length size one byte short of that length causes Java to throw the error, even though there's nothing thread-unsafe, and I'm working with two different variables.

To top it off I can use CharsetDecoder and it'll still fail.  I'll chalk it up to an OS JVM bug. Without that freakish fix, the code works fine in other OS's and JVMs.